# Select any entity created today

Tags: 7, database, datetime

One of an entity properties is a timestamp, set when it was created.

I want to use the [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class to load entities that were created today.

Normally, I would write a query using `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_timestamp), "%Y-%m-%d") = "2014-03-17"`.

I'm not aware of any method to use any MySQL functions in `EntityFieldQuery`. I have tried with the following code.

```
$day_start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $created_ts));
$day_end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $created_ts));
$query->propertyCondition('created', $day_start, '>')
  ->propertyCondition('created', $day_end, '<');
```

Whilst this works, it doesn't seem as efficient and certainly less succinct. Is there a function that I can use with `EntityFieldQuery` similar to [`SelectQuery::where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::where/7) that would allow to write code similar to the following one?

```
$query->propertyWhere('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), "%Y-%m-%d")', "2014-03-17");
```

Comment: You may or may not have problems with this general approach due to timezones (eg, database storing UTC and having `$created_ts` reflect local time).

Comment: Good point - I'll have to be aware of this and fix if/when required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code , PropertyCondition accepts range values using BETWEEN operator.. Since timestamp is stored as int in database node table created column with data and time together below code works to fetch records of a particular date..

```
<?php
$day_start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $created_ts));
$day_end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $created_ts));
$query
    ->propertyCondition('created', array($day_start, $day_end), 'BETWEEN');
?>
```

Find more about [propertyCondition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apropertyCondition/7) in D.O

Comment: This unquestionably more succinct :)

Answer (score 2):

No there's no such method in `EntityFieldQuery`. If you take your code here:

```
$query
  ->propertyWhere('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), "%Y-%m-%d")', "2014-03-17");
```

Just imagine what Drupal would have to do to determine *which* property (column) you're referring to here. It would have to parse the SQL string and pull out the `created` string before it can get the field meta data - arguably an expensive and unnecessary step.

Since an `EntityFieldQuery` is only supposed to be used for query entities by property/field, the methods provided are (necessarily) limited. I think your less-succinct method is the best you'll get without subclassing and extending.

Comment: I was imagining that it wouldn't have to work out which field it was at all. As this is a property and not a field Drupal knows it will refer to a field in the base table of the entity, so I was hoping it could just attach the SQL to the generated query. Why does it need the field meta data?

Comment: Sorry you're right, it doesn't, but there's still no `propertyWhere` or equivalent - I imagine to avoid unnecessary confusion. I've been developing in Drupal full time for 4 years and I've never had the need to do this, for example

Comment: Do you think this is a feature that adds enough benefit that it could / should be added in future (in core or contrib)?

Comment: Sure, certainly wouldn't hurt to have that extra helper method and would make things a wee bit easier in this situation for some people.

Comment: In despite it is a property and not a field, Drupal would need to parse the SQL string to add the table prefix. Also it should use an alias to grant no collision.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the `EntityFieldQuery` class to load entities that were created today.

In that case, you don't need the equivalent of `SelectQuery::where()`.

If the creation date cannot be set to any date in the future, you can simply use the following code.

```
$query->propertyCondition('created', strtotime('today'), '>=');
```

Otherwise, I would use the following code.

```
$query->propertyCondition('created', array(strtotime('today'), strtotime('today 23:59:59')), 'BETWEEN');
```